# How do I preserve the current viewport when removing a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0fqts8p/). Essentially, I have 3 really long divs. At the end of the second div, I have a button that, on clicked, removes the first div. The problem is that removing this div makes the page scroll to the end. How do I prevent this behaviour and keep the viewport intact when this happens?

```
<div id="first">
    <p>Some really long content ...</p>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <p>Some really long content... </p>
</div>
<button onclick="$('#first').remove()">Remove First div</button>
<div id="third">
    <p>Some really long content ...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the behaviour explained by you is expected. To maintain back on the current position, you will need to adjust the viewport scroll's position. For example, updated in your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d0fqts8p/1/

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    var firstElHeight = $('#first').height();  // get the height of element to be deleted
    var currentHeight = $("body").scrollTop(); // get the current scroll position
    $('#first').remove();
    $("body").scrollTop( currentHeight - firstElHeight);  //calculate and set back
});
```